# Can images be reflected as a shadow using css?

Tags: html, css, shadow

I've been seeing a lot of designs with this style :

[Image Reflection Shadows](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/1400/7f417933379937.56a93f8814836.png)

Sample of image showing reflection:

[image: Cropped to pertinent part of image]
I'm just wondering if this is even possible to code. I've been searching for a way to do this but found no luck. I just want some clearance on this. Is it just for looks or is it possible?

Comment: I think there is no easy way to do that with CSS will be easier to export the image that way .... But here is one try: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNZvLN

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! You can do this with CSS and `filter: blur();`

Demo http://jsbin.com/nidekeyajo/edit?html,css,js,output

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.shadow {
  bottom: -30px;
  filter: blur(20px);/* this is the magic part */
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.95);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="image" src="https://lorempixel.com/800/450/nature/3/" alt="rocky shore">
  <img class="shadow" src="https://lorempixel.com/800/450/nature/3/" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, i knew there is a better answer than mine. +1

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Ted! This was exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: @SergioEstrada No problem! Just be aware that only the most recent versions of IE support CSS filters http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 3):

I have not come across anything like the described; *however,* you might be interested in the following

[Using CSS Filter property to Create Ambient-Light round Images](http://codepen.io/shoowack/pen/IGDev)

*it works better when there's high contrast between the colors and the background*

**All credit to original author on Codepen.io**

```css
body {background: #111}

.img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px;
  height: 236px;
  width: 420px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 50px 100px -30px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.img:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  filter: blur(50px) contrast(3);
  z-index: -1;
}

.first, .first:after {
  background: url("http://images.smh.com.au/2013/02/13/4028970/--art_wrestling_20130213154720739962-420x0.jpg");
}

.second, .second:after {
background: url("http://images.theage.com.au/2014/04/02/5317898/ZAH_hawk_LW-20140402235602816699-420x0.jpg");
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="img first"></div>
<div class="img second"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure. You have to use CSS3 `-webkit-box-reflect: below;` 
Nice variety of examples are [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-reflection/)

Comment: Nice to know this one. I tried this one `-webkit-box-reflect: below -5px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(89%, transparent), to(white));`